# ASPX PDF conversion

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to convert current aspx page on button click in to PDF without using third party tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing built in, so you have to use third party tools.

I have seen [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) recommended here many times as a good PDF library, though I have not used it myself. It is free.

[Here](http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/itextsharp-simplify-your-html-to-pdf-creation/) is a blog post about rendering HTML + CSS to a PDF with this library.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that iTextSharp is AGPL, so using it may have licensing ramifications for your application.

Answer (score 0):

what if you do a report in Reportviewer.. you will have great control over the layout!